# How to add a column using withcolumn by performing some transformation on existing columns?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple csv file with columns`(id:Integer,Name:String,Gender:String)`. I want to add a column to this dataframe using withColumn. I am aware that first parameter is column name but not quite sure how to pass the second parameter which will group by the gender. Can someone help me with this?

I have tried using `df.withColumn("Count",df.groupby("Gender").count())` but it is giving type mismatch error saying it is expecting a column type but getting a dataframe. I have tried using `col()` also expecting it to type cast it.

```
val newDf=df.withColumn("count",col(df.groupBy("Gender").count()))
```

I expect a new dataframe with count column added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, use of `window` function and `count` function

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "name1", "M"),
  (2, "name2", "M"),
  (3, "name3", "M"),
  (4, "name4", "M"),
  (5, "name5", "F"),
  (6, "name6", "F"),
  (7, "name7", "M")
).toDF("id", "Name", "Gender")

val window = Window.partitionBy("Gender")

df.withColumn("count", count($"Gender").over(window))
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+------+-----+
|id |Name |Gender|count|
+---+-----+------+-----+
|5  |name5|F     |2    |
|6  |name6|F     |2    |
|1  |name1|M     |5    |
|2  |name2|M     |5    |
|3  |name3|M     |5    |
|4  |name4|M     |5    |
|7  |name7|M     |5    |
+---+-----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, It works. Also one additional question, is there any way to count the gender of people in same city. Suppose if i had an additional city column and two male and 3 females in that city. How do i do count gender city wise?

Comment: Yes, you do this by passing multiple columns in `partitionBy`

Comment: can you accept as an answer if this helped and works?

Comment: Great that works too. Thanks a lot. I accepted it as an answer

Comment: There is a problem with this approach that i feel. If i have mulitple entries with the same city name, it gets printed everytime and it looks redundant. How to make it look like an sql groupby?

Comment: If you want to group, you need to use groupBy, I think its better to ask another question with more details like input and output.